# Report Server does not refresh in sync with Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Report Server is not refreshing my report while Report manager is. Now I did have to alter the aspx files for both as the date parameters for my reports were showing in an American Date Format as per this website , http://geekswithblogs.net/naijacoder/archive/2008/06/26/123422.aspx

Any idea why this is happening ? Deleting the data sources, data sets and reports and redeploting does not work for Report Server either. Ahhhhh !

Comment: if you deploy it to a new folder or with a different name does it work properly?

Comment: Tried it with a different name and that did not work.  I can try a different folder and see if that works?